# Want to filter document category under specific site

Tags: document-library

I am no expert, but our SharePoint admin at work got retrenched while building our team site and now I need to complete the site !

most of it is done expect I need to fix the document filter for each sub site. for example;

Main site = Department

Subsite = Sub Department 1

Subsite = Sub Department 2

Our document library has sub-categories for both sub departments that are all together.

however, when I click on Sub Department 1 I only want to see documents that are categorised for sub-department 1 and not include 2 as well as it is at the moment ?

i hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the view to not show Sub Department 1 in Sub department 2 like this.

[image]

Or if you have multiple departments, you can set it to "is equal to".